# Soap Request in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I need to generate a Soap request in Java. This is the xml file that I need to generate and pass through:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     
   xmlns:ns="website"         
   xmlns:com="website/Common" 
   xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RequestName>
         <ns:model>
            <ns:keys query="myquery;" ></ns:keys>
            <ns:instance></ns:instance>
         </ns:model>
      </ns:RequestName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am aware that there are other methods of doing this, such as wsimport, but I would like to know how to do it this way. My this way way, I mean what is the correct Java syntax in create the xml file for a Soap Request. Here is some very basic syntax:

```
 SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
 SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
 SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

 // Here is the XML it produces:
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    ...
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: what you mean 'this way'?

Comment: Technically generating this xml and streaming it is a *way*.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: What is the correct Java syntax in generating this xml file for a Soap Reuqest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with following code:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns", "website");
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("com", "website/Common");
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xm", "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime");
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement element = soapBody.addChildElement("RequestName", "ns");
SOAPElement modelElement = element.addChildElement("model", "ns");
SOAPElement soapElement = modelElement.addChildElement("keys", "ns");
soapElement.addAttribute(envelope.createName("query"), "myquery;");
modelElement.addChildElement("instance", "ns");

soapMessage.saveChanges();
soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
```

This will produce following output:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:com="website/Common" 
    xmlns:ns="website" 
    xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:RequestName>
            <ns:model>
                <ns:keys query="myquery;"/>
                <ns:instance/>
            </ns:model>
        </ns:RequestName>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```